# How do I get on a Minecraft PE server when it says 'invalid name'?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am having trouble getting onto a server in Minecraft PE on iOS. When I tap on the person's server it just says `invalid name`:

[image]

I have tried turning off and restarting the iPad, going to home screen and logging back into the server but I have had no luck and no change. Is there a reason why this is so?

Comment: I am not sure why this is downvoted...My kids had the same problem, I googled "Minecraft PE InvalidName" and this question came up frist. The answer below worked great.

Comment: @Joe Downvotes are for the question itself as it is rather sparse, lacks a lot of details that could have helpped and showed complete lack of research, as by the time this question was asked, there were 2 identical questions already on the site. The answer gets seperate upvotes for its usefulness.

Answer (score 18):

My kids had this problem after the update. Exit the game to the title screen, go into settings, and change your name to one without spaces or special characters. Then it will let you join other worlds again.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running the server you can install a plugin to allow all usernames.

[Plugin is here](http://forums.pocketmine.net/plugins/namecorrector.1270/)