# Can't enter a username?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to enter a username, I start to type it but nothing is showing up, it's just blank and I have double tapped swiped and retried and I have also shut down my device and opened it again but this still doesn't help

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get on a Minecraft PE server when it says 'invalid name'?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/222302/how-do-i-get-on-a-minecraft-pe-server-when-it-says-invalid-name)

Comment: I don't think this is a copy, as the answer to the other question involved entering a name, which is what this user is having trouble with, in the first place

Comment: Yes, I can't enter anything @Timelord64

Comment: Have you been using §s or hacks?